# Rolling average postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, window-functions

I am running Postgres 9.2 and I have a large table something like

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_values
(
  ts timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  value double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NaN'::real,
  sensor_id integer NOT NULL
)
```

I have values coming into the system constantly ie many per minute. I want to maintain a rolling standard deviation / average for the last 200 values so I can determine if new values entering the system are within say 3 standard deviations of the mean. To do so I would need the current standard deviation and mean to be constantly updated for the last 200 values.
As the table can be hundreds of millions of rows I do not want to get the last say 200 rows for a sensor ordered by time and then do vg(value), var_samp(value) for every new value coming in. I and assuming it will be faster to updated the standard deviation and mean.

I have started writing a PL/pgSQL function to update a rolling variance and mean on each new value entering the system for a particular sensor.

I can do this using code pseudo like

```
newavg = oldavg + (new_value - old_value)/window_size
new_variance += (new_value-old_value)*(new_value-newavg+old_value-oldavg)/(window_size-1)
```

This is based on
http://jonisalonen.com/2014/efficient-and-accurate-rolling-standard-deviation/

Basically the window is of size 200 values. The old_value is the first value of the window. When a new value comes in we shift the window forward one. After I get the result I store the following values for the sensor

```
The first value of the window.
The mean average of the window values.
The variance of the window values.
```

This way I don't have to constantly get there last 200 value and do a sum etc.I can reuse this values when a new sensor value come in.

My problem is when first running I have no previous window data for a sensor ie the three values above so I have to do it the slow way.

something like

```
WITH s AS
        (SELECT value FROM sensor_values WHERE sensor_values.sensor_id = $1  AND ts >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '2 day')::timestamptz ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 200)
    SELECT avg(value), var_samp(value)  INTO last_window_average, last_window_variance FROM s;
```

But how could I get the last value (ealiest) to save from that select statement ?
Can I access the first row from s in PL/pgSQL.

I thought PL/pgSQL would be faster / cleaner approach but maybe its better to do this is client code ?
Are there better ways to perform this type on rolling statistic update ?

Comment: What about `avg(value) over (partition by sensor_id order by ts rows between 200 preceding and current row) as avg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that it will not be drastically slow to re-calculated latest 200 entries each time with proper indexing. If you'll do an index, like:

```sql
CREATE INDEX i_sensor_values ON sensor_values(sensor_id, ts DESC);
```

you'll be able to get results fairly quickly doing:

```
SELECT sum("value") -- add more expressions as required
  FROM sensor_values
 WHERE sensor_id=$1
 ORDER BY ts DESC
 LIMIT 200;
```

You can execute this query in a loop from `PL/pgSQL` function.
If you'll migrate to 9.3 (or higher) any time soon, you'll be able to also use [`LATERAL` joins](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) for this purpose.

I do not think a covering index will do a good thing here, as table is constantly changing and `IndexOnlyScan` will not kick in.

It is good to check [Loose Index scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan) also.

P.S. Column name `value` should be double quoted, as this is an [SQL reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Comment: Hmm doing 
SELECT sensor_id, value 
FROM sensor_values
WHERE sensor_id=555 ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 200;
Took over two minutes as it has to order all the data. 1 second cached.
http://explain.depesz.com/s/DbN

Doing 
SELECT ts, value FROM sensor_values WHERE sensor_values.sensor_id = 540 AND ts >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '2 day')::timestamptz ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 200 takes 100 ms 
. 
When I could get a thousand new entries a minute I think this is too much overhead.
I think the indexes are working ok.
Maybe I can make it non realtime every 1000 or so entries.

Comment: @GlennPierce, You haven't mentioned partitioning. Of course, to get a proper partition pruning you need to add an appropriate predicate. Can you show plan for the second query, please?

Comment: Plan for second query
    http://explain.depesz.com/s/tXrD
Not sure why it has to check partition tables for earlier years

Comment: @GlennPierce, this is because planner is not good with expressions on partitioning keys. Try to pre-calculate the value (in the client code or in the  PL/pgSQL function) and use it as a constant, like `ts >= '2015-04-22'::timestamptz`.